# indirection operator of auto_gcroot class

Tags: c++-cli

auto_gcroot class does not have public indirection operator(`operator*`).
However, code sample below has been successfully compiled. Why is so?

```
auto obj = *(std::static_pointer_cast<const auto_gcroot<Object^>>(pObj))
```

Comment: That is not C++, maybe C++/CLI?

Comment: It's a deceptive language name.  C++/CLI is _not_ C++.

Answer (score -2):

[`std::static_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) returns a `std::shared_ptr` (In this case, a `std::shared_ptr<const auto_gcroot<Object^>>`), which does have an `operator*`.

`*std::static_pointer_cast<T>(pObj)` is an lvalue of type `T`, so `obj` will be a copy of the `auto_gcroot<Object^>` object stored by the shared_ptr.